# Unicode character that hides the characters after it

Tags: text, unicode, encoding, character

is there any unicode character (more than one is okay) that hides/squashes all the characters after it, like John **UNICODE CHARACTER**Smith. The Smith is hidden/made as small as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Hiding/diminishing and other text decoration is not a matter of unicode. It is a matter of text rendering I think.

Comment: I don't know, I think there's an unicode character that makes everything after it right-to left.

Comment: That's an exception. Right-to-left writing is a relevant and stable habit of quite a few cultures. Unicode has to deal with that. Hiding text is something very different.